# Ember.js correct syntax for passing closure actions to nested components

Tags: ember.js

When passing a closure action down through some nested components, is there a difference between passing the action down using the action helper (First image), and simply passing the action down as a property (Second image)?

[image: Passing action down with the action helper]

[image: Passing action down as a property]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR; no.

The former was the original and documented implementation of [closure actions](https://www.axiomq.com/blog/introduction-to-ember-closure-actions/) in Ember. However, the latter works just as well in Ember 2.10 or later and is compatible with the future simplified [Glimmer component proposal](https://glimmerjs.com/api/projects/_glimmer_component/modules/component).

There are some gotchas using the latter syntax, however, you might accidentally override some important Component methods like `destroy()`.

For more background information, see [Actions best practices](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/actions-best-practices-should-we-even-use-the-actions-hash-at-all/13178/3)

You may also be interested in the [Events deep dive](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/deep-dive-on-ember-events-cf684fd3b808) which will explain all the differences between various ways of handling events in Ember.

This answer was written at the time of Ember 3.1, and should work for versions 2.10 - 3.x.